# Identifying a specific text from a document without OCR the entire image

Tags: python, opencv, contour

We have several forms without a specific format but almost all containing some same fields. The forms are hand filled.

We want to extract data from some specific fields. The location of the field is not constant. Even the layout of the form is not constant. However, the handwritten relevant data is typically on the right of the field heading which is printed.

Probably doing OCR for the entire page and then trying to get the relevant field is one of the options but for efficiency we would like to identify the area of interest and OCR only relevant part especially because handwriting OCR is very costly.

I understand OpenCV can identify text zones and even contours in an image. Any chance I can identify my area of interest using the printed field name without running a full OCR.

Edited for more clarity.
The attached invoice would make a perfect example. With that kind of an image how do we read the GST No (circled) only without doing a complete OCR.
[image: Sample Bill Image]

Comment: Can you add some samples you are working on ?

Comment: Edited the original question and added an example